# New Year 2017 Puzzle: Two of Four Diophantine Equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics

What is the smallest number $n$ which can be described with equation $(1)$ *and* one or more of equations $(2.1)-(2.3)$, where all variables are prime numbers?
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = n \tag{1}$$
$$d^2 + e^2 -1 = n    \quad\tag{2.1}$$
$$f^2 + f \cdot g + g^2 = n \tag{2.2}$$
$$h = n^4 + (n-1)^4 + (n+1)^4\tag{2.3}$$

Is there a second solution for all four equations together?
I let the computer check the first million of primes without success.

Comment: When you say "prime number equations", do you mean to say that $a,b,c$ are primes?

Comment: Does $n$ have to be a prime as well?

Answer (score 3):

One solution:
$$a=b=7, \quad c=11$$
$$d=13, \quad e=43$$
and, quite fittingly,
$$
n=2017.
$$

Comment: This solution also has $n^4+(n-1)^4+(n+1)^4=49652974982033$ which is prime, and $n=41^2+41\cdot 7 + 7^2$. Thus, it satisfies all of the equations.